# spring boot + cxf rest json/xml providers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cxf

I implement a simple project with spring boot and cxf rest services and i am trying to figure out what is going on with xml/json providers.

- **no providers at** **CxfConfig :**
  when i @Produce("application/xml") it returns to me a valid xml
  when i @Produce("application/json") i get *No message body writer has been found for class com.cxfexample.dto.User, ContentType: application/json*
- **providers at CxfConfig :**

```java
    @Configuration
    public class CxfConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Autowired
    MyServiceIntf peService;

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(peService));
        endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(jacksonJaxbJsonProvider(), jaxbElementProvider()));
        return endpoint.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jacksonJaxbJsonProvider() {
        return new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public JAXBElementProvider jaxbElementProvider() {
        return new JAXBElementProvider();
    }
}
```

when i @Produce("application/xml") **or** @Produce("application/json") it works fine but when i implement **both** of them i get valid only the dataformat of first argument of @Produce({"application/xml","application/json"})

**Question 1** so there is a default mapper for xml and not for Json?

**Question 2** the error message *No message body writer has been found for class* refers to the provider's absense or to an annotation error to my Pojo User?When i remove the @XmlRootElement i get also this message for the application/xml produce.

**Question 3** when i use providers why i get valid data only the for the first argument of  @Produce({"application/xml","application/json"}) and so when i request this service e.g with postman my content-type is only application/xml and not both of them

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cxfexamle</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxfexample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>CXFExample</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CXF RS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}


@Path("/Rest")
public interface MyServiceIntf {

    @GET
    @Path("/getUser")
    @Produces({"application/json","application/xml"})
    User getUser();
}


@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyServiceIntf {
    @Autowired
    User user;

    @Override
    public User getUser() {
        user.setUserName("David");
        user.setPassword("123");
        return user;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement
@Component
public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    @XmlElement    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    } 
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1 so there is a default mapper for xml and not for Json?

Yes, JAXB is shipped with JVM since 1.6. It is a Java to XML mapper. Mapping to JSON requires an additional library like Jackson or Jettison

> Question 2 the error message No message body writer has been found for class refers to the provider's absense or to an annotation error to my Pojo User?

It means CXF could not serialize the object. You need to add a serialization provider or configure JAXB.

> Question 3 when i use providers why i get valid data only the for the first argument of @Produce({"application/xml","application/json"})

You need to set the `Accept` header at client side to the desired content type. CXF will generate a response according the acceptable media types or the first one in `@Produces` if you do not specify anyone